# Is it possible to import Excel file with dynamic sheet name into SQL Server table using EF in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamic

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExcelView(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = string.Empty;

            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                string conString = string.Empty;

                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;

                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                }

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

                using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                            // Get the name of First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema;

                            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "dbo.tblStores" });
                            string ALLRISStores = dtExcelSchema.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
                            // String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                            connExcel.Close();

                            // Read Data from First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            // string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);


                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [ALL RIS Stores$]";
                            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;

                            odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                            connExcel.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Insert records into database table.

                NECCOI_DBEntities1 entities = new NECCOI_DBEntities1();

                if (entities.tblStores.Count() == 0)
                {
                    // ViewBag.Message("Data does not exist, so uploading data");
                    Log.Error("Data does not exist, so uploading data");

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        //Div Mkt Store IP  TID Corp Fran flag  Address City    County State   Zip Hours   tmz MO?  Gas? Gas integrated 
                        //    Gas Vendor Reg Citgo TID   Voice Store Closed Date   RIS Installation
                        entities.tblStores.Add(new tblStore
                        {
                            Div = Convert.ToString(row["Div"]),
                            Mkt = Convert.ToString(row["Mkt"]),
                            Store = Convert.ToString(row["Store"]),
                            IP = Convert.ToString(row["IP"]),
                            TID = Convert.ToString(row["TID"]),
                            Corp_Fran_flag = Convert.ToString(row["Corp Fran flag"]),
                            Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]),
                            City = Convert.ToString(row["City"]),
                            County = Convert.ToString(row["County"]),
                            State = Convert.ToString(row["State"]),
                            Zip = Convert.ToString(row["Zip"]),
                            Hours = Convert.ToString(row["Hours"]),
                            tmz = Convert.ToString(row["tmz"]),
                            MO_ = Convert.ToString(row["MO?"]),
                            Gas_ = Convert.ToString(row["Gas?"]),
                            Gas_integrated = Convert.ToString(row["Gas integrated"]),
                            Gas_Vendor = Convert.ToString(row["Gas Vendor"]),
                            Reg = Convert.ToInt32(row["Reg"].ToString()),
                            Citgo_TID = Convert.ToString(row["Citgo TID"]),
                            Voice = Convert.ToString(row["Voice"]),
                            Store_Closed_Date = row["Store Closed Date"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Store Closed Date"]),
                            RIS_Installation = row["RIS Installation"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["RIS Installation"]),
                            Planned_Open_date = row["Planned Open date"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Planned Open date"])


                            //Store_Closed_Date = (DateTime?)(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Store Closed Date") ? row["Store Closed Date"] : (object)DBNull.Value),
                            //RIS_Installation = (DateTime?)(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("RIS Installation") ? row["RIS Installation"] : (object)DBNull.Value),
                            //Planned_Open_date = (DateTime?)(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Planned_Open_date") ? row["Planned_Open_date"] : (object)DBNull.Value)

                            // Store_Closed_Date= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("Store Closed Date") ? (object)DBNull.Value: (object)Store_Closed_Date,

                            //Store_Closed_Date = row["Store Closed Date"] = null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Store Closed Date"])
                            //RIS_Installation = row["RIS Installation"] = null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["RIS Installation"]),
                            //Planned_Open_date = row["Planned_Open_date"] =null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Planned_Open_date"])

                            //Store_Closed_Date = null,
                            //RIS_Installation = null,
                            //Planned_Open_date = null
                        });
                        ViewBag.Result = "File Imported Successfully";
                        Log.Error(ViewBag.Result);
                    }

                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    //ViewBag.Message("Data Already Exist,So Deleting the Existing data");
                    Log.Error("Data Already Exists,So Deleting the Existing data and Uploading New Data");
                    entities.tblStores.RemoveRange(entities.tblStores);
                    entities.SaveChanges();


                    //NECCOI_DBEntities1 entities = new NECCOI_DBEntities1();
                    //Log.Error(entities);
                    //Log.Error(entities.tblStores);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        //Div Mkt Store IP  TID Corp Fran flag  Address City    County State   Zip Hours   tmz MO?  Gas? Gas integrated 
                        //    Gas Vendor Reg Citgo TID   Voice Store Closed Date   RIS Installation
                        entities.tblStores.Add(new tblStore
                        {
                            Div = Convert.ToString(row["Div"]),
                            Mkt = Convert.ToString(row["Mkt"]),
                            Store = Convert.ToString(row["Store"]),
                            IP = Convert.ToString(row["IP"]),
                            TID = Convert.ToString(row["TID"]),
                            Corp_Fran_flag = Convert.ToString(row["Corp Fran flag"]),
                            Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]),
                            City = Convert.ToString(row["City"]),
                            County = Convert.ToString(row["County"]),
                            State = Convert.ToString(row["State"]),
                            Zip = Convert.ToString(row["Zip"]),
                            Hours = Convert.ToString(row["Hours"]),
                            tmz = Convert.ToString(row["tmz"]),
                            MO_ = Convert.ToString(row["MO?"]),
                            Gas_ = Convert.ToString(row["Gas?"]),
                            Gas_integrated = Convert.ToString(row["Gas integrated"]),
                            Gas_Vendor = Convert.ToString(row["Gas Vendor"]),
                            Reg = Convert.ToInt32(row["Reg"].ToString()),
                            Citgo_TID = Convert.ToString(row["Citgo TID"]),
                            Voice = Convert.ToString(row["Voice"]),
                            Store_Closed_Date = row["Store Closed Date"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Store Closed Date"]),
                            RIS_Installation = row["RIS Installation"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["RIS Installation"]),
                            Planned_Open_date = row["Planned Open date"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Planned Open date"])


                            //Store_Closed_Date = (DateTime?)(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Store Closed Date") ? row["Store Closed Date"] : (object)DBNull.Value),
                            //RIS_Installation = (DateTime?)(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("RIS Installation") ? row["RIS Installation"] : (object)DBNull.Value),
                            //Planned_Open_date = (DateTime?)(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Planned_Open_date") ? row["Planned_Open_date"] : (object)DBNull.Value)

                            // Store_Closed_Date= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("Store Closed Date") ? (object)DBNull.Value: (object)Store_Closed_Date,

                            //Store_Closed_Date = row["Store Closed Date"] = null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Store Closed Date"])
                            //RIS_Installation = row["RIS Installation"] = null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["RIS Installation"]),
                            //Planned_Open_date = row["Planned_Open_date"] =null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Planned_Open_date"])

                            //Store_Closed_Date = null,
                            //RIS_Installation = null,
                            //Planned_Open_date = null
                        });
                        ViewBag.Result = "File Imported Successfully";
                        Log.Error(ViewBag.Result);
                    }

                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [ALL RIS Stores$]";  in my code i have given sheet name  i.e ALL RIS Stores, so only it will upload data from excel sheet contains "ALL RIS Stores" only but i need with any sheet name it should upload, is it possible, if yes please guide me , i am new to MVC